SVG with straight lines and gradient mask not rendering
I am trying to create a sort of flowing pipes effect using svg on my website.
This works great:


<svg width="100%" viewBox="0 0 360 182" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">

<defs>
      <linearGradient id="gradient">
        <!-- white shows, black hides-->
        <stop offset="0" stop-color="white" stop-opacity="0" />
        <stop offset="0.8" stop-color="white" stop-opacity="1" />
        <stop offset="0.8" stop-color="white" stop-opacity="0" />
      </linearGradient>

      <mask id="gradient-mask">
        <rect class="mask-rect" x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%" fill="url(#gradient)" />
      </mask>
    </defs>

<path d="M0.507812 1C42.1439 1 100.783 9.24797 157.913 28.9564C221.89 51.0272 307.193 56.9128 360 56.9128" stroke="#3EDBDB" stroke-width="2" mask="url(#gradient-mask)"/>
<path d="M0 61.3269C47.7292 61.3269 97.9278 61.9341 150.296 67.2125C208.688 73.098 318.364 77.5122 360 77.5122" stroke="#FF41EC" stroke-width="2" mask="url(#gradient-mask)"/>
<path d="M0 120.673C47.7292 120.673 97.9278 120.066 150.296 114.788C208.688 108.902 318.364 104.488 360 104.488" stroke="#3EDBDB" stroke-width="2" mask="url(#gradient-mask)"/>
<path d="M0.507812 181C42.1439 181 100.783 172.752 157.913 153.044C221.89 130.973 307.193 125.087 360 125.087" stroke="#FF41EC" stroke-width="2" mask="url(#gradient-mask)"/>
</svg>



Those wires are curved. For straight lines, it's not working:


<svg viewBox="0 0 220 74" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <defs>
    <linearGradient id="a">
      <stop offset="0" stop-color="#fff" stop-opacity="0"/>
      <stop offset=".8" stop-color="#fff"/>
      <stop offset=".8" stop-color="#fff" stop-opacity="0"/>
    </linearGradient>
    <mask id="b">
      <rect class="mask-rect-two" width="100%" height="100%" fill="url(#a)"/>
    </mask>
  </defs>
  <path d="M0 1 H220" stroke="#000" stroke-width="2" mask="url(#b)"/>
  <path d="M0 25 H220" stroke="#000" stroke-width="2" mask="url(#b)"/>
  <path d="M0 49 H220" stroke="#000" stroke-width="2" mask="url(#b)"/>
  <path d="M0 73 H220" stroke="#000" stroke-width="2" mask="url(#b)"/>
</svg>



If I remove the mask from each path, the lines appear. Also, if I optimize the SVG on pasteSVG into one path, the lines work too, but I want to control the color of each wire so I cannot do that. Thank you!
HEre's the merged example from clicking optimize on pasteSVG


<svg viewBox="0 0 220 74" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><defs><linearGradient id="a"><stop offset="0" stop-color="#fff" stop-opacity="0"/><stop offset=".8" stop-color="#fff"/><stop offset=".8" stop-color="#fff" stop-opacity="0"/></linearGradient><mask id="b"><rect class="mask-rect-two" width="100%" height="100%" fill="url(#a)"/></mask></defs><path d="M0 1h220M0 25h220M0 49h220M0 73h220" stroke="#000" stroke-width="2" mask="url(#b)"/></svg>




Try <mask id="b" maskUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%">
